# hyperlink in excel doesn't load properly, but from PDF or word loads fine

Tags: excel, hyperlink, business-objects

We have a Business Objects (BO) report, that formats a hyperlink to the front-end application for a particular entry; so that you can go straight to the data entry screens for that record in the report.

- Link works properly from Business Objects in the browser.
- Link works properly from a Word document saved from BO.
- Link works properly from a PDF document saved from BO.
- Opening the XLS file in OpenOffice Calc, links work fine.
- Opening the XLS in Excel and the links fail, with an error message from the application as if the security was timed-out or the user hasn't logged into the application properly.  (Which doesn't happen for any of the other non-browser based applications, if the application is open in another tab and the user is signed in.)

When the URL parts are copied out of any of the formats/applications, they match exactly.  The application redirects to the error message page, so I can't say for certain what URL hits the browser from Excel, only the results.  The other applications end up at the page listed in the `href` attribute.

Is there anything that can be done to alter the `href` part of the link, so that it works from Excel?  (As a sub-question, any hints as to why Excel's hyperlink behavior is different from the other MS Office apps would be appreciated.)

My Google-Fu isn't strong enough with this one, most of what I've found with the keywords I've tried have been directions on how to link from Excel, not troubleshoot failed outcomes of an otherwise valid hyperlink.

Link general form (in case that matters): https://*server.domain.com*/*path*/*page*?*parameters=uniqueID*

Comment: posting the actual error from excel would help

Comment: Might help to install Fiddler, to see exactly what is happening with the URL.

Comment: No error message from Excel, but the results in the browser are FUBAR when the link is clicked from within Excel (the other formats work fine, including another spreadsheet program that opens the XLS file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cell format to text. It has worked for me in the past when hyperlinks fail to work.

Comment: I'll try that, but wouldn't the link "effect" go away when it's set to plain text?

"Go Here" would be replaced by <a href="url">Go Here</a>

Comment: I know that you cannot mix text and links in one cell. It may only read as <a href="url">Go Here</a> as you said. But try it out and add this to the formula bar "=HYPERLINK(A1)".  Where A1 is the cell it is in.

Comment: Format change on the column is a no-go, still not opening a new tab in the browser and getting to the proper data-entry page from Excel.  (But the other file formats/applications work just fine with the same initial conditions.)
Using the hyperlink function will be a non-starter for this issue, as we are looking for ease of use, not having the end users need to recreate something that's already there, just to please Excel.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean non-starter for the issue. Most of what I am reading either says you need to use a macro (which is doable but more work). The other option is using the hyperlink function.

Try one for thing for me just to see if it works. 
Add 

=HYPERLINK("http://"&A2) 

to the formula bar and have only this text in cell A2:

server.domain.com/path/page?parameters=uniqueID   **(No http://)**